# Sequelize Error: Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am receiving the error when I make a call to my API with a get request:

```
Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.
```

My Models look like this:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Productions = sequelize.define("productions", {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.SMALLINT,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        setupTime: {
            type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(6, 3)
        },
        notes: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        }
    }, { timestamps: false });

    return Productions;
};
```

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const ProductionPrints = sequelize.define("productionPrints", {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.SMALLINT,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        compDate: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE
        }
    }, { timestamps: false });

    return ProductionPrints;
};
```

The relationship between the models is defined here:

```
db.productions = require("./productions.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.productionprints = require("./production-prints.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);

db.productions.hasOne(db.productionprints, {
    foreignKey: {
        name: 'productionId',
        allowNull: false
    }
});
db.productionprints.belongsTo(db.productions, { foreignKey: 'productionId' });
```

And the sequelize query looks as so:

```
const db = require("../models");
const Productions = db.productions;
const ProductionPrints = db.productionPrints;

exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    Productions.findAll({
        include: [ { model: ProductionPrints, as: 'prints' } ]
    })
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                    err.message || "An error occurred while finding the productions."
            });
        });
};
```

I have checked around for others with the issue but have had no avail with any solutions posted on those problems. Generally it was caused by typos, or error in the require paths. I have checked those and all my other includes work, just not on any of the models I include on the productions model.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error was being caused by a typo:

```
db.productions = require("./productions.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.productionprints = require("./production-prints.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
```

when this was being referenced in the assigned to a constant:

```
const Productions = db.productions;
const ProductionPrints = db.productionPrints;
```

shame on me for changing my case use:

```
db.productionprints != db.productionPrints
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , this is usually caused by naming issue , to track the issue you can check one of the following places to resolve it

1. check if you are calling the correct model class name
2. when importing models becarefull not to call the file name instead of model name => the one exported

3.check if you got your association correctly by calling the exported model not the file name

4. check if your cases e.g users vs Users.

a bonus tip is to use same name for model and file name to avoid these issues because the moment you make them different you likely to make these mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer of Kelvin Nyadzayo, i have the *model.findOne(options)* method with a
**options.include** like this:`include: [ { } ]` in the options parameter

The include has to have the proper syntax: `[{model: Model, as: 'assciationName'}]`

And the mine was empty

So this, was triggering the same error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).